# Require calling method M after setting property P

Tags: swift, setter, private-members

I have a property and a method:

```
class C {
    var myProperty = ""
    func myFunc() {

    }
}
```

I would like to have a rule that when you set `myProperty` you *must* then proceed to call `myFunc`. Of course I can have a *mental* rule that requires this, but a mental contract is no contract at all. I want to *enforce* this contract through the class's API.

(**NOTE** All of this is purely about what goes on *inside* C. Both `myProperty` and `myFunc` can be private as far as visibility *outside* C is concerned; that doesn't affect the problem.)

Obviously we can do this with a setter observer:

```
class C1 {
    var myProperty = "" {
        didSet {
            self.myFunc()
        }
    }
    func myFunc() {

    }
}
```

However, there's something I don't like about that solution: it relies upon what amounts to a hidden side effect. It is up to me to know that saying `self.myProperty = "..."` also triggers a call to `myFunc`. I don't like that kind of hidden side effect; it makes my code harder to understand, and violates one of my key programming principles, Say What You Mean.

What *do* I mean? I mean something like this:

```
self.setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc("...")
```

I like that, because it tells me exactly what this call does every time it occurs in my code. So we could write this:

```
class C2 {
    var myProperty = ""
    func myFunc() {

    }
    func setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc(_ s:String) {
        self.myProperty = s
        self.myFunc()
    }
}
```

But there's a problem with *that*, namely that it is now possible to set `myProperty` without calling `myFunc`, breaking the rule that we set out to enforce in the first place! The only way I've found to enforce that rule is to have *another* class that defends the property with privacy. For example:

```
class C3 {
    class Inner {
        private(set) var myProperty = ""
        private func myFunc() {

        }
        func setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc(_ s:String) {
            self.myProperty = s
            self.myFunc()
        }
    }
    let inner = Inner()
}
```

That is in fact what I'm doing, but it seems a bit nutty to have a second class just to enforce these privacy and naming rules. My question is: Is there another way?

Comment: Make the property private and the `setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc` function public. And if you also need to access the property outside, write a public getter function.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing in my C3 solution. That can't work without the Inner class, though, because a private property of a class remains settable from within that class. All of this is about what goes on _inside_ the class. (Maybe I should be clearer about that?)

Comment: what about rename your myProperty to myPropertyDidSetMyFunc ?

Comment: Then I believe the only way to go is C1. Relying on hidden side effects is not exactly elegant solution, but I guess that's what property observers exist for in Swift., and that is an explicit requirement.

Comment: @JIEWANG That's not a completely bad suggestion (the name would be more like `myPropertyAndSettingItCallsMyFunc`), though it's not really much better than C1 plus a comment every time I set `myProperty` to remind myself that I'm also calling `myFunc`.

Comment: I’d lean towards C3 w/out the nested classes. The other logical approach is a read-write computed property w its own backing stored property (because it’s harder to accidentally bypass the main property and work directly with backing stored property ... it becomes a more conscious decision). But I’d only use `C3`/`Inner` pattern if that inner type was a useful abstraction that helped simplify the design of C3.

Comment: This is one of those questions that is a little hard to answer in the abstract, but when considering specific example, the right design would likely be more obvious. I might suggest creating a less abstract example and posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Rob Well, between C1, C3, and Rob Napier's answer, we probably have all the options, which was my goal. I used to have C1; now I have C3; I might or might not adopt Rob Napier's approach, or I might even revert to C1. I can make the decision; I just want to make sure I'm playing with a full deck of cards before I decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though I don't know if it's actually any better. You can hide `myProperty` inside of a closure rather than inside of a class/struct. For example:

```
class C {
    public var myProperty: String { return _myPropertyGetter() }
    public func setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc(value: String) {
        _myPropertySetter(self, value)
    }

    func myFunc() {
        print("myFunc")
    }

    private let (_myPropertyGetter, _myPropertySetter): (() -> String, (C, String) -> ()) = {
        var property = ""
        return ({ property }, { property = $1; $0.myFunc() })
    }()
}

let c = C()
c.myProperty
c.setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc(value: "x")
c.myProperty
```

There's a lot of complexity here, like passing `self` to `_setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc` to allow `myFunc` to live outside the closure, and maybe some of that could be dispensed with. But the basic idea is to generate two functions that are the only functions that have access to the property storage, making it "super-private" without creating an inner class.

If you don't need `myFunc()` to be public (and from your Inner example, I think you don't), then you can do it a little simpler, and this almost might be better than Inner.

```
class C {
    public var myProperty: String { return _myPropertyGetter() }
    public func setMyPropertyAndCallMyFunc(value: String) { _myPropertySetter(value) }

    private let (_myPropertyGetter, _myPropertySetter): (() -> String, (String) -> ()) = {
        var property = ""
        func myFunc() {
            print("myFunc")
        }
        return ({ property }, { property = $0; myFunc() })
    }()
}
```

Comment: Ingenious! I would never have thought of that.